# Creating and reading files to be manually transferred to or from Windows

Tags: android, windows, android-11

First, let me say that today is the first time I've ask a question on SO, so please be tolerant if I don't phrase my question according to the rules or make myself clear. I have reviewed these problems in SO and can't seem to find an up-to-date solution THAT ACTUALLY WORKS.

My problems deal with creating and accessing files being transferred between Windows and Android 11.

I have an android karaoke app that reads karaoke files previously transferred from Windows. I manually created a 'Karaoke' folder on an external SD card and manually copied the karaoke MP3 and CDG files into that folder's sub-folders. I was then able to programmatically access those files within my app. Under Android 11, I can still access the MP3 files but not the CDG files. What is the best option to solve this problem.

Likewise, I was backing up my app database located in protected storage to the removable SD card. I could then manually transfer the backup files to Windows. This no longer works under Android 11. What is the best option to solve this problem.

Comment: Hard to believe that you cannot access all files from same folder.

Comment: Also hard to believe that from windows pc you cannot access all files on sd card.

Comment: "I can still access the MP3 files but not the CDG files" -- we cannot help you to debug code that we cannot see. "This no longer works under Android 11" -- again, we cannot help you to debug code that we cannot see. Overall, the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) would seem to fit your use cases. For example, [here is a sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.6/ImportExport) that backs up and restores a Room database using `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.